# Vba Worksheet(1).Activate instruction: 408 Error (The object doesn't admit this property or mehtod)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to copy and paste values in another excel spreadsheet:

```
Sub createSpreadSheet()

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
szToday = Format(Date - 1, "YYYYMMDD")
    With NewBook
        .Title = "Informe_Control_Colaterales_ddmmaaaa"
        .Subject = "Informe_Control_Colaterales"
        .SaveAs Filename:="V:\Departamento\7920-SOLVENCIA\1. Riesgo de Mercado\2. RIESGO DE CONTRAPARTIDA\1. REPORTING DIARIO R.Contrapartida\1. Enviados\Informe_Control_Colaterales_" & szToday & ".xls"
    End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("H1", "K37").Select
Selection.Copy
NewBook.WorkSheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = "CSA y REPO Restrospectivoo"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "CSA y REPO Actual"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
Nows = "CSA y REPO Actual"
Worksheets(Nows).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
NewBook.Sheets(2).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
NewBook.Sheets(1).Activate


End Sub
```

When it executes the instruction `NewBook.WorkSheets(1).Activate` I get the error described in the title of this query. I've tried also to put `NewBook.Sheets(1).Activate`, but in that case the code execution simply ignore the instruction and doesn't activate "Newbook" and executes the rest of the code in "ThisWorkBook" wrongly.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `WorskSheets` - is this just a typo in your question?

Comment: Instead of `ActiveSheet` specify the worksheet you mean, e.g. `Set SourceSheet = Worksheets("CSA y REPO Actual")` and `SourceSheet.Cells.Select` and so forth.

Comment: @SJR Yes, sorry.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO And how I do to specify it on the instruction `Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "CSA y REPO Actual"`?

Comment: Can you correct it then please?

Comment: In two steps like this: `Set MyWorkSheet = WorkSheets.Add(After = Sheets(Worksheets.Count))` then `MyWorksheet.Name = "Whatever the name is"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on how to avoid select and activate. Try this. It's not entirely clear which workbook you are referring to in every case so may need some tweaking.

```
Sub createSpreadSheet()

Dim NewBook As Workbook, szToday

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
szToday = Format(Date - 1, "YYYYMMDD")

With NewBook
    .Title = "Informe_Control_Colaterales_ddmmaaaa"
    .Subject = "Informe_Control_Colaterales"
    .SaveAs Filename:="V:\Departamento\7920-SOLVENCIA\1. Riesgo de Mercado\2. RIESGO DE CONTRAPARTIDA\1. REPORTING DIARIO R.Contrapartida\1. Enviados\Informe_Control_Colaterales_" & szToday & ".xls"
    .Worksheets(1).Name = "CSA y REPO Restrospectivoo"

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("H1", "K37").Copy
    .Worksheets("CSA y REPO Restrospectivoo").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Worksheets("CSA y REPO Restrospectivoo").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    'in the line below not clear which workbook this refers to so may need changing
    .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Worksheets.Count)).Name = "CSA y REPO Actual"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CSA y REPO Actual").UsedRange.Copy
    .Sheets("CSA y REPO Actual").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Sheets("CSA y REPO Actual").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .Sheets(1).Activate
End With

End Sub
```